# Move gas oven away from wall

Tags: gas, oven

We are painting the wall behind our gas oven today, and we'd like to pull the oven forward a couple inches to be able to paint behind the oven a little bit.

The oven is on a wood floor so I'm hesitant to brute force pull it forward because I don't want to damage the floor.

Also, I'm not sure of the safety of doing this.  The oven is about 9 years old and I would think the gas line is flexible, but I'm not sure.

Any tips for moving the oven or should we just skip it and paint around the edges as best we can?

Comment: Lift the front of the oven enough to slip plastic sheets or equivalent under them.  THis makes it easier to slide and won't scratch the floor.  And don't worry about the gas line- it was flexed when the stove was installed;  if it were to break when you pull out, it would be about to snap on its own. Far better it happen when you're right there to shut off the feedvalve.

Comment: A warning on [flexible gas appliance connectors](http://www.texasinspector.com/files/Flexible-Connector.pdf): "Connectors are designed for occasional movement after installation. Not for use on castered equipment. Repeated bending, flexing or extreme vibration will cause metal fatigue and must be avoided."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old bath towels work very well to protect floors if you double or quad fold them. Lift on the front of the kitchen range unit to get the towel in under the front feet or base.

Then slide out the range unit the few inches needed. It can actually be helpful to have one person pulling out on the top back of the range (which transfers the weight of the unit onto the front feet or base) whilst at the same time have another person tug on the end of the towel stack to help nudge the range out from the wall.

When you have the unit pulled out is also a good opportunity to inspect and clean the area behind the range.

Answer (score 1):

The feet of all ranges I have moved (20+ of them) are smooth and rounded and have not scratched the floor.

But go by the sound it makes when it starts to move:  if it sounds like it is gouging or scratching, stop moving immediately and place a protective item under the front feet like a towel, folded newspaper, paper towel, cardboard, etc.